# Не компилируется код QT\Ubuntu 12.04: error: 'inet_addr' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt

Здравствуйте! Я в QT новичек, можно сказать, что только вот впервые сел за него... Помогите понять что не так в программе... Писал сперва консольный вариант программы для работы с сокетами... Всё компилировалось и работало в Ubuntu. Начал создавать графический интерфейс в QT появились ошибки... Вот часть кода где они возникают:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<stdio.h> //for printf
#include<string.h> //memset
#include<sys/socket.h>    //for socket ofcourse
#include<stdlib.h> //for exit(0);
#include<errno.h> //For errno - the error number
#include<netinet/tcp.h>   //Provides declarations for tcp header
#include<netinet/ip.h>    //Provides declarations for ip header

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
........

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
....
       strcpy(source_ip , "1.1.1.1");
       sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
       sin.sin_port = htons(445);
       sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.18.4.96");-----------------!!! вот тут.....
....
       int psize = sizeof(struct pseudo_header) + sizeof(struct tcphdr) + strlen(data);
       pseudogram = malloc(psize);--------------------------!!! и тут

..............
}
```

QT Выдает такие сообщения об ошибках:

```
../mainwindow.cpp:101: error: 'inet_addr' was not declared in this scope

../mainwindow.cpp:143: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

Что не так? В консольном исполнении всё работало.

Comment: наверняка пропустили какой-нибудь `#include`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пишем в консоли: `man inet_addr`. И получаем в первых строках список необходимых заголовков:

```
   #include <sys/socket.h>
   #include <netinet/in.h>
   #include <arpa/inet.h>
```

Добавьте в Вашу программу то, чего не хватает, и сообщите о результате.

Comment: Да, спасибо, всё заработало!

Answer (score 2):

По поводу первой ошибки смотрите ответ коллеги [[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)'а.

По поводу второй -- в чистом C можно присвоить значение типа `void*` переменной типа `char*`, а в C++ нельзя, так что нужно явное преобразование типов:

```
pseudogram = static_cast<char*>(malloc(psize));
```

---

Однако же обращение к интернету в функции с названием `on_pushButton_clicked` наводит на мысль, что вы блокируете UI-поток потенциально очень медленным кодом. Выучите многопоточное программирование, и все операции, не относящиеся к UI, делайте в отдельных потоках. Иначе ваша программа будет подвисать.

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает!!!)))

Comment: А можете подсказать в какой каталог ставится QT Creator в Ubuntu?

Comment: @Alerr: нет, сорри, у меня с этим никакого опыта